# How to display values according to it's name in DetailView yii2?

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to display `category` values according to it's name, not id. I'm trying to do like so:

```
[
   'attribute' => 'category_id',
    'value' => 'category.name',
],
```

But then attribute doesn't get displayed. It displays: `name` instead of `Category`. Category name is displayed correctly.

Also tried `'category.name'` ,but it's displaying same values, and `'category_id'` is displaying label correctly, but the name - according to id's.

How should I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you define relation for category, like this?

```
public function getCategory()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Category::className(),['id'=>'category_id']);
}
```

If you want to display in GridView, you can do it like you

```
[
   'attribute' => 'category_id',
    'value' => 'category.name',
],
```

If you want to display in DetailView, you can do it like this

```
[
   'attribute' => 'category_id',
    'value' => $model->category ? $model->category->name : '',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you need  a label.

the simplest way is add the label direcly in the  detail view item

```
[
  'label' => 'Category',
  'attribute' => 'category_id',
  'value' => ....,

],
```

Comment: This doesn't work too. Label is putting correctly, but instead of real category name it's printing just  `'category.name'`.

Comment: If  you need  the related  value and not  label .. then update you question add  you related  model and controller acttion ..